# What can I expect to change about how I write python on my Mac after I install conda?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda, miniconda

**Background**

Currently, I have Python **2.7.17** and Python **3.8.1** installed on my Mac (v **10.14.6**). Both Python versions were downloaded directly from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) using a "macOS 64-bit installer" .pkg file, in late 2019. Both were installed here:

python2: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2` 
python3: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3`

Currently, I use only `pip` (either `pip2` or `pip3`, depending) to install python packages, which are saved here:

python2: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.X/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
python3: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

I am about to begin an online course which requires that I install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) in order to install the packages that I need for the course. But after having a very bad experience having Anaconda installed on my machine years ago, and it taking me months to remove it and re-create a clean Python install, I am nervous. **I don't want my machine to become a mess again, rife with error messages that it can't find this or that python version or this or that python library.**

**Question(s)**

- Assuming there will now be multiple installations of Python on my machine (in addition to the versions that I already have, since I believe yet another version of python is installed along with conda), and there will be new places where python packages will be saved, **what can I expect to change about how I write python after I install miniconda?**
- Is there anything I will need to do differently from what I am doing now when I write python code?
- How can I ensure that everything remains working and compatible and I avoid the fate I suffered many years ago?

Happy to edit/clarify this question per user suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conda environments and install Python into those environments. This ignores, by design, the versions of Python that are installed at the system level. Also, what's installed into environments (other than the one you're in) is ignored. As somebody who uses conda for all Python development, I don't even know what I have installed in `/usr/local/bin/` or other places. Everything is in `/path/to/miniconda3/envs/env_name_n`. You don't have to uninstall other versions of Python you have elsewhere; the point of environments is to keep everything isolated.

> What can I expect to change about how I write python after I install miniconda?

> Is there anything I will need to do differently from what I am doing now when I write python code?

Use conda environments and use `conda` as your package manager. For almost every major project, it nearly a drop-in replacement for `pip`. Outside of managing dependencies, not much changes.